# How to modifify a LDAP atrribute using the sAMAccountName?

Tags: java, ldap, jndi

I'm trying to change the expiracy date of a LDAP account in Java.

I have a servlet which load a list of potential accounts and the user will select one, choose a date and click on 'update'

Then I will perform some checks, for example verify if the new date is set after the previous one.
So I load the attributes of the selected account.

Now when everything is OK I want to perform the update but I don't get what should be the 'name' attribute of the modify method.
I wanted to use the sAMAccountName.

Here is the code :

```
// Récupération des infos sur le compte a modifier :        
            Hashtable env = new Hashtable();
            env.put(InitialDirContext.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION,"simple");
            env.put(InitialDirContext.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, userLDAP);                    
            env.put(InitialDirContext.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, passwordLDAP);
            env.put(InitialDirContext.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
            env.put(InitialDirContext.PROVIDER_URL, urlLDAP);

            DirContext ldapCtx = new InitialDirContext(env);
            SearchControls searchCtls = new SearchControls();
            
            // Paramétrage des critères de recherche et des attributs a retourner
            searchCtls.setReturningObjFlag(false);
            searchCtls.setSearchScope(SearchControls.SUBTREE_SCOPE);
            String[] attrIDs = {"displayName", "sAMAccountName", "accountExpires", "memberof","crnrDomainassoc01position"};
            searchCtls.setReturningAttributes(attrIDs);
            String searchBase = "OU=VPN,OU=Exterieurs,DC=chu,DC=lan"; 

// searchFilter based on the selected user on the liste compteVPN
            String searchFilter = "(&(objectCategory=User)(sAMAccountName=" + compteVPN + "))";
            
            NamingEnumeration<SearchResult> answer = ldapCtx.search(searchBase, searchFilter, searchCtls);

            while (answer.hasMoreElements()) 
            { 
                SearchResult sr = (SearchResult)answer.next();          
                
                Attributes attrs = sr.getAttributes();          
                
                displayName = attributeToString(attrs.get("displayName")); 
                System.out.println(" --> displayName : " + displayName);            
                sAMAccountName = attributeToString(attrs.get("sAMAccountName")); 
                memberof = attributeToString(attrs.get("memberof")); 
                crnrDomainassoc01position = attributeToString(attrs.get("crnrDomainassoc01position")); 
                accountExpires = attributeToString(attrs.get("accountExpires")); 
                
                java.util.Date expiracy = timeToDate(accountExpires);                         
                accountExpiresFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("'le' dd/MM/yyyy 'à' kk:mm:ss").format(expiracy) ;
            }

// retrieve the new date, perform some checks ... then

        // Attribut a modifier
            Attribute attribute = new BasicAttribute("accountExpires", dateToTime(dateExpirationMarge));
            // array of modified iteams
            ModificationItem[] item = new ModificationItem[1];
            // replacing the value
            item[0] = new ModificationItem(DirContext.REPLACE_ATTRIBUTE, attribute);
            // changing the value of the attribute
            ctx.modifyAttributes(?????????, item);
```

What should I put instead of ???????? ?
Thanks for your help, this LDAP thing is driving me crazy :)

**EDIT:**
Following EricLavault's input I used *sr.getName()* but I get the following error :

*javax.naming.NamingException: [LDAP: error code 1 - 000020D6: SvcErr: DSID-03100836, problem 5012 (DIR_ERROR), data 0 ]; remaining name 'CN=Maintenance Axians'*

Those are the results of the context search done just before :

**sAMAccountName** : axians
**displayName** : Maintenance Axians
**memberof** :
CN=Pso10-DSI,OU=PSO,OU=CHUSTE,DC=chu,DC=lan|CN=Vpn_Tout,OU=VPN,DC=chu,DC=lan

I tried to modify the displayName to Maintenance_Axians removing the space since my research pointed an issue with LDAP not handling spaces correctly but it didn't solve my issue

*javax.naming.NamingException: [LDAP: error code 1 - 000020D6: SvcErr: DSID-03100836, problem 5012 (DIR_ERROR), data 0
]
javax.naming.NamingException: [LDAP: error code 1 - 000020D6: SvcErr: DSID-03100836, problem 5012 (DIR_ERROR), data 0
]; remaining name 'CN=Maintenance_Axians'*

Comment: You should put the dn of the entry you want to modify, or the relative dn (relative to the context on which the operation is performed), ie. if the context is the same as for the search operation, then `sr.getName()` or `sr.getNameInNamespace()` should be fine.

Comment: Thx a lot for your anwser but I got an error with this method :

_javax.naming.NamingException: [LDAP: error code 1 - 000020D6: SvcErr: DSID-03100836, problem 5012 (DIR_ERROR), data 0
 ]; remaining name 'CN=Maintenance Axians'_
 
. Those are the results of the search done just before :
**sAMAccountName** : _axians_
**displayName** : _Maintenance Axians_
**memberof** : _CN=Pso10-DSI,OU=PSO,OU=CHUSTE,DC=chu,DC=lan|CN=Vpn_Tout,OU=VPN,DC=chu,DC=lan_

I'm using the same context.
From my search about the error message it looks like it can't find the name but I don't know why

Comment: I found a link talking about a problem with spaces in the names : [LDAP SEARCH DN DOESNT SUPPORT SPACES](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/apar/LI78510) but the srName I get have none :
**srName** : _axians_ .